# Awesomium with OpenGL Texture Shift

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, awesomium

I'm trying to use awesomium with opengl (glut and cpp) and I'm having trouble rendering the webpages to textures. The textures are randomly (different every time I run the program) shifted in the x and y axis. Picture: [image: Shifted Texture]

I thought GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE would take care of that problem but it did not. What am I doing wrong?

The Awesomiumpart:

```
    web_core = WebCore::Initialize(WebConfig());
    view  = web_core->CreateWebView(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    WebURL url(WSLit(URL));
    view->LoadURL(url);
    BindMethods(view);
    while (view->IsLoading())
        web_core->Update();
    Sleep(300);
    web_core->Update();
    surface = (BitmapSurface*)view->surface();
```

The part loading the texture:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0,
        GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface);
```

Comment: Found a solution. Copying the surface via surface->CopyTo into a unsigned char * and using that as a texture works.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I know you solved the problem, but it might help someone in the future.

```
int w = surface->width();
int h = surface->height();

unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[w * h * 4];
surface->CopyTo(buffer, w * 4, 4, false, false);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

delete[] buffer;
```